# multiple ssl with iis

Tags: iis, ssl

We have IIS6.0. We have a website running it's own certificate. Up until now that has been the only SSL site we're hosting. We are adding another, with it's own certificate. It's not working. What is the correct and best way to accomplish this? We have multiple IP's available, etc. Research has led me to the claim that we can't use host headers, which is what I believe we are doing now. Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use host headers if you like, it's just not possible to set it all up using the IIS snap-in.

Details here:
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/596b9108-b1a7-494d-885d-f8941b07554c.mspx?mfr=true

and here:
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/596b9108-b1a7-494d-885d-f8941b07554c.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: I understand that, thanks. We have 2 seperate certificates. We do not want to use the wildcard solution. Other thoughts welcome.

Comment: Found this and it worked for us. We were trying to use external IP, and change the IIS entry to listen for a specific external IP, whereas what really needs to be done is you add another IP to the NIC card under advanced settings, then forward traffic to that IP.  Here is the link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501530/can-iis6-0-host-two-ssl-certificates

Comment: @ArlenHarris answer your own question and mark it as correct. It will help the rest of us.